# How can I perform arithmatic operations between elements of two lists with no common key in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, calculation

I have two lists with  different attributes. However the final result is calculated based on a combination of two attributes picking one from each List. There is no common key between them. The following is my code--

```
import math
import json

# First list
with open("acc.json") as data_file:

    list1 = [json.loads(line) for line in data_file]

for acce in list1:
    Xaxis = float(format(float(acce['dataX']),'.4f'))
    Yaxis = float(format(float(acce['dataY']),'.4f'))
    Zaxis = float(format(float(acce['dataZ']),'.4f'))


    #Second list

with open("gyro.json") as data_file2:

   list2 = [json.loads(line) for line in data_file2]

for gyro in list2:
    pitch=float(format(float(gyro['dataX']),'.4f'))
    roll=float(format(float(gyro['dataY']),'.4f'))
    yaw=float(format(float(gyro['dataZ']),'.4f'))

    gX=float(-g * math.cos(pitch)*math.sin(roll))
    gY=float(-g * math.sin(pitch))
    gZ=float(g * math.cos(pitch) * math.cos(roll))

#Below code is not working

for (k,v),(k2,v2) in zip(my_dict.iteritems(), my_dict2.iteritems()):

    linAcceX=float((Xaxis-gX)/g)
    linAcceY=float((Yaxis-gY)/g)
    linAcceZ=float((Xaxis-gZ)/g)

    print linAcceX,"--",linAcceY,"--",linAcceZ
```

The error I am getting is

```
for (k,v),(k2,v2) in zip(my_dict.iteritems(), my_dict2.iteritems()):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

I am using python 2.7 at this moment. I have written the inline comments as far as possible. Both the list codes are running fine separately.

INPUT File 
'acc.json'

```
{"dataX":"- 0.9621435403823853","dataY":"2.9307477474212646","dataZ":"8.861872673034668"}
{"dataX":"-1.1992958784103394","dataY":"3.096036195755005","dataZ":"8.895410537719727"}
{"dataX":"-2.95518159866333","dataY":"2.7582736015319824","dataZ":"6.964654445648193"}
```

'gyro.json'

```
{"dataX":"0.07588004320859909","dataY":"0.06340815126895905","dataZ":"-0.08991656452417374"}
{"dataX":"-0.010938923805952072","dataY":"0.12412817031145096","dataZ":"0.036317165940999985"}
{"dataX":"-0.054614730179309845","dataY":"0.015471287071704865","dataZ":"0.00968557596206665"}
```

These are actual data so that the output seems realistic.

Comment: `my_dict` is a list, not a dictionary.

Comment: The first `for` loop is overwriting the 3 variables each time. So the rest of the code will just use the values from the last line in the file. Is that what you intended?

Comment: I am a beginner in python, so any way to solve it ?

Comment: Solve what? You haven't explained what the code is supposed to do, and what it's doing wrong.

Comment: No, for each iteration the operation should be performed with corresponding elements.

Comment: Maybe the `for gyro` loop should be nested inside the `for acce` loop, so you process every combination of the two lists.

Comment: one acc reading with one gyro reading. Wouldn't a nested loop perform one to many combination? A one to one combination for all items in both the list is required.

Comment: We need those jsons (you can mock up a fake one if you don't want to give us proprietary data) if we're going to be able to run your code and help you.

Comment: One big red flag is how you're loading the jsons. You want something like
my_dict = json.loads(data_file.read())

Comment: At present I am more concerned about the combination operation issue. That JSON load is working fine, and not exactly my problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you call `my_dict` is not a dictionary, so it does not have a `iteritems` method.  It's a list, which you iterate properly with:

```
for acce in my_dict:
    ...
```

To iterate on the two lists together use

```
for acce, gyro in zip(my_dict, my_dict2):
    # access items like you do before
    # acce['dataX']
    # within this loop you might be able to do

    for (k,v),(k2,v2) in zip(acce.iteritems(), gyro.iteritems()):
        ...
```

To fully test this I'd have to reconstruct your lists or JSON structures.  You may need to provide a minimal example with real data, along with expected results (you can probably skip all the `math` details, since the focus is on iterating through the data structures.

With your samples - copy-n-paste as lists of dictionaries.  (PY3)

```
In [1]: list1=[{"dataX":"- 0.9621435403823853","dataY":"2.9307477474212646","dataZ":"
   ...: 8.861872673034668"}, 
   ...: {"dataX":"-1.1992958784103394","dataY":"3.096036195755005","dataZ":"8.8954105
   ...: 37719727"}, 
   ...: {"dataX":"-2.95518159866333","dataY":"2.7582736015319824","dataZ":"6.96465444
   ...: 5648193"}]                                                                   
In [2]: list2=[{"dataX":"0.07588004320859909","dataY":"0.06340815126895905","dataZ":"
   ...: -0.08991656452417374"}, 
   ...: {"dataX":"-0.010938923805952072","dataY":"0.12412817031145096","dataZ":"0.036
   ...: 317165940999985"}. 
   ...: {"dataX":"-0.054614730179309845","dataY":"0.015471287071704865","dataZ":"0.00
   ...: 968557596206665"}]                                                           
  File "<ipython-input-2-91a4ce8928da>", line 3
    {"dataX":"-0.054614730179309845","dataY":"0.015471287071704865","dataZ":"0.00968557596206665"}]
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

In [3]: list2=[{"dataX":"0.07588004320859909","dataY":"0.06340815126895905","dataZ":"
   ...: -0.08991656452417374"}, 
   ...: {"dataX":"-0.010938923805952072","dataY":"0.12412817031145096","dataZ":"0.036
   ...: 317165940999985"}, 
   ...: {"dataX":"-0.054614730179309845","dataY":"0.015471287071704865","dataZ":"0.00
   ...: 968557596206665"}] 

In [4]: for x, y in zip(list1, list2): 
   ...:     for (k,v),(k2,v2) in zip(x.items(), y.items()): 
   ...:         print(k,k2,v,v2) 
   ...:                                                                              
dataX dataX - 0.9621435403823853 0.07588004320859909
dataY dataY 2.9307477474212646 0.06340815126895905
dataZ dataZ 8.861872673034668 -0.08991656452417374
dataX dataX -1.1992958784103394 -0.010938923805952072
dataY dataY 3.096036195755005 0.12412817031145096
dataZ dataZ 8.895410537719727 0.036317165940999985
dataX dataX -2.95518159866333 -0.054614730179309845
dataY dataY 2.7582736015319824 0.015471287071704865
dataZ dataZ 6.964654445648193 0.00968557596206665
```

I'm using py3, so use `item()` instead of `iteritems()`.

Comment: Actually I want to construct a list3 that will have the value of gX,gY and gZ. Then the nested loop will call list1 and list3 to perform the operations. How to create and populate such list in python?

Comment: Append values to lists.

Comment: actually the final result will compute  linAcceX=float((Xaxis-gX)/g)
    linAcceY=float((Yaxis-gY)/g)
    linAcceZ=float((Xaxis-gZ)/g)
so each of Xaxis,Yaxis,Zaxis , gX,gY,gZ need to be individually accessible without assuming any ordering. Do I need to create 6 separate lists for this and then use nested for as shown? moreover the new lists will have only values and no keys as contrast to JSON data. I can do it with a 2D array if it was 'C' language, but no idea to achieve the same in python. I have used list=[] then under for loop list.append(Xaxis) to store Xaxis values successfully.

Comment: The list will contain a series of (Xaxis,Yaxis,Zaxis) tuples that is a list within another list, I suppose.So should I create 3 individual lists that is, list1=[all Xaxis values], list2=[all Yaxis values], list3=[all Zaxis values] and another 3 for gX,gY,gZ ? list.extend([Xaxis,Yaxis,Zaxis]) is doing the same, but how to access individual elements?[ something like a[i][j] in 'C']